# Application crashed when variables start, end, user and dest are undefined, how to avoid this?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Trying to insert variables start, end, user and dest in the database through a web app, but they are sometimes(randomly) undefined which makes them unreadable in this function leaving a 'TypeError'.
Using db2 and nodejs.

**js-file:**

```
app.post('/setAlarm', function(request, response) {

var start = request.body.start;
var end = request.body.end;
var user = request.session.username;
var desc = request.body.desc;
var queryin = "INSERT INTO ALARMS (START, END, USERNAME, DESCRIPTION) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
...
```

**html-file** where I want to assign the variables from:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Set Alarm Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/alarm.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/navbar.css">
    <script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
 </script>
    <script type ="text/javascript" src ="js/jqueryFuncs.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body id = "alarmPage">
    <header class="header">
        <h1>Set Alarm Page</h1>
        <input id = "logout" type = "submit" onclick="logout();" value 
 ="Logout"></input>
    </header>
    <ul class="navbar">
        <li class="navbar"> <a class="navbar" href="/index">Home</a></li>
        <li class="navbar"> <a class="navbar" 
 href="/AboutTheProject">About 
 the Project</a></li>
        <li class="navbar"> <a class="navbar" href="/AboutUs">About Us</a> 
 </li>
        <li class="navbar"><a class="login" href="login.html">Login</a> 
 </li>
        <li class="navbar"><a class="navbar" 
  href="registration.html">Registration</a></li>
        <li class="navbar"><a class="setAlarmLink" 
 href="setAlarm.html">Set 
  Alarm</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class ="setAlarm">
          <form action="setAlarm" method="POST">
          <label>Enter start time</label><br>
          <input id ="start" name = "start" placeholder ="start" type = 
  "time" required><br>
          <label>Enter end time</label><br>
          <input id = "end" name ="end" placeholder="end" type = "time" 
 required> <br>
          <label id = "descr">Enter description</label><br><br>
          <textarea name="desc" placeholder="Enter description here" 
 cols="20" rows="3"></textarea><br>
          <input id ="submitAlarm" type="submit" value="Set Alarm">
          </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This  is the **Error message**:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of undefined
at C:\Users\abc\Documents\03_Kurser\db-error-fix\public\js\alarm.js:10:15
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\abc\Documents\03_Kurser\db- 
error
-fix\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\Users\abc\Documents\03_Kurser\db-error- 
fix\node_modules\express\li
b\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\abc\Documents\03_Kurser\db-error- 
fix\node_modules\
express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\abc\Documents\03_Kurser\db- 
error
-fix\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at C:\Users\abc\Documents\03_Kurser\db-error- 
fix\node_modules\express\lib\rout
er\index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\abc\Documents\03_Kurser\db-error- 
fix\node
_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (C:\Users\abc\Documents\03_Kurser\db-error- 
fix\node_modules\express\li
b\router\index.js:275:10)
at serveStatic (C:\Users\abc\Documents\03_Kurser\db-error- 
fix\node_modules\ser
ve-static\index.js:75:16)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\abc\Documents\03_Kurser\db- 
error
-fix\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (C:\Users\abc\Documents\03_Kurser\db-error- 
fix\node_modules\exp
ress\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
at C:\Users\abc\Documents\03_Kurser\db-error- 
fix\node_modules\express\lib\rout
er\index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\abc\Documents\03_Kurser\db-error- 
fix\node
_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (C:\Users\abc\Documents\03_Kurser\db-error- 
fix\node_modules\express\li
b\router\index.js:275:10)
at expressInit (C:\Users\abc\Documents\03_Kurser\db-error- 
fix\node_modules\exp
ress\lib\middleware\init.js:40:5)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\abc\Documents\03_Kurser\db- 
error
-fix\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: Why don't you check if request.body exists?

Comment: show your error(whole) and also the full html file

Comment: Okay good! I check for request.body and it keeps the app from crashing.
Now, why is the object missing? 
The form should pass an object to the function stated above by doing this?
     <form action="setAlarm" method "post">  ...
@soltex

Comment: Done! Seems correct to me :/ 
@GaneshJadhav

Comment: @Jarmojo just keep in mind that your carefully designed form is only one of the ways your backend will be called.  Someone could make the requests directly using any HTTP client.  For this reason, it's important to validate any request bodies your backend receives.  This includes making sure they're below a certain length, and validating their presence and format.

Comment: @Jarmojo it is unwise to use reserved-words as column-names (START and END are both reserved words in SQL). Mistakes like that eventually bite you...

Comment: Thank you @ctt, I'm obviously very new at this, especially node.
Just trying to set up some basic functionality. 
Also, just realized how good this forum is!

Comment: @mao I'll have that in mind going forward, thank you!